# How to set the 'iss' claim of JWT using Flask-JWT-Extended's create_access_token()

Tags: python, flask, jwt, flask-jwt-extended

Is there a way to set the iss claim of the JWT that is generated by create_access_token of Flask-JWT-Extended?

I tried to put the iss claim under the parameter 'user_claims' of the create_access_token:

```
access_token = create_access_token(
   identity=data['username'],
   expires_delta = timedelta(seconds=JWT_LIFE_SPAN),
   user_claims={'iss': ISSUER}
)
```

However, when I decoded the token using PyJWT from the side of resource server, it looked like this:

```
{'iat': 1597581227, 'nbf': 1597581227, 'jti': '4e6c9677-d698-421c-91c4-0b2f3a6da4e9', 'exp': 
1597583027, 'identity': 'asdf', 'fresh': False, 'type': 'access', 'user_claims': {'iss': 
'sample-auth-server'}}
```

I tried to look for a configuration options from the [docs](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options/#header-options), but I can't find any option to set the iss. There's an iss set, but it is under the user_claims.  What I want to accomplish is to set it as one of the [registered claims](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1) for the JWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make use of `encode_access_token` api and create an encoded access code with issuer.

Example:

```
 encode_access_token(
    identity=data['username'],
    issuer=JWT_ISSUER,
    expires_delta=timedelta(seconds=JWT_LIFE_SPAN),
    ...
 ):
```

Reference : https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/blob/5bd8b1ed08ea64d23869a629af3c3c868816b8a8/flask_jwt_extended/tokens.py#L34

Comment: The issuer parameter of encode_access_token is not yet in the latest release version 3.24.1